# Writing a generic iterator in Java for Binary Tree

Tags: java, generics, iterator, iterable

I want to write a custom iterator for BinaryTree. This iterator should return `Node<?>` objects. I get compile error in file `InorderIterator` in lines with recursive call to fillList: `fillList(currentNode.getLeft());`

The error is: `Error:(14, 37) java: incompatible types: rclib.Node cannot be converted to T`

Can somebody explain me why my approach doesn't work? Or how to fix it

`Node.java`

```java
package rclib;

public class Node<T extends Comparable<T>> {
    T key;
    Node<T> left;
    Node<T> right;
    public Node(T key, Node left, Node right) {
        this.key = key;
        this.left = left;
        this.right = right;
    }

    public Node(T key) {
        this(key, null, null);
    }

    public Node<T> getLeft() {
        return left;
    }

    public Node<T> getRight() {
        return right;
    }

    public T getKey() {
        return key;
    }
}
```

`InorderIterator.java`

```java
package rclib;
import java.util.*;

public class InorderIterator<T extends Node<?>> implements Iterator<T> {
    LinkedList<T> list;

    public InorderIterator(T root) {
        list = new LinkedList<T>();
        fillList(root);
    }

    public void fillList(T currentNode) {
        if (currentNode == null) return;
        fillList(currentNode.getLeft());
        list.add(currentNode);
        fillList(currentNode.getRight());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return !list.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public T next() {
        return list.removeFirst();
    }
}
```

`AVLTree.java`

```java
package rclib;

public class AVLTree<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterable<Node<T>>{
    private Node<T> root;

    @Override
    public Iterator<Node<T>> iterator() {
        return new InorderIterator<Node<T>>(root);
    }
}
```

Comment: Aside: `public Node(T key, Node left, Node right) {` should be `public Node(T key, Node<T> left, Node<T> right) {`.

Comment: Do you actually want an iterator over *nodes*, or over *values*?

Comment: i want iterator over Nodes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should perhaps do something like that:

```
package rclib;
import java.util.*;

public class InorderIterator<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterator<Node<T>> {
    LinkedList<Node<T>> list;

    public InorderIterator(Node<T> root) {
        list = new LinkedList<Node<T>>();
        fillList(root);
    }

    public void fillList(Node<T> currentNode) {
        if (currentNode == null) return;
        fillList(currentNode.getLeft());
        list.add(currentNode);
        fillList(currentNode.getRight());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return !list.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public Node<T> next() {
        return list.removeFirst();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to explicitly specify that you use `Node` and not `? extends Node` which might finally be not qualified for the correct usage.

```
public static class InorderIterator<T extends Comparable<T>> implements Iterator<Node<T>> {
    LinkedList<Node<T>> list;

    public InorderIterator(Node<T> root) {
        list = new LinkedList<>();
        fillList(root);
    }

    public void fillList(Node<T> currentNode) {
        if (currentNode == null) return;
        fillList(currentNode.getLeft());
        list.add(currentNode);
        fillList(currentNode.getRight());
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        return !list.isEmpty();
    }

    @Override
    public Node<T> next() {
        return list.removeFirst();
    }
}
```